# Insert Loop from select in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I insert 1 rows successfully, but I want to insert rows using loop. The purpose is want to insert into table2 values of table1 that is not existed. My query like that:

```
FOR cl1 IN (SELECT tb1.cl1 FROM table1 tb1 WHERE tb1.cl1 NOT IN(SELECT tb2.cl1 FROM table2 tb2))
LOOP
  INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (cl1,'123456',sysdate);
END LOOP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT tb1.cl1, '123456', sysdate
FROM table1 tb1 
WHERE tb1.cl1 NOT IN(SELECT tb2.cl1 FROM table2 tb2)
```

Your sub-query using `NOT IN` will not work as you expect it, if the column `cl1` contains `NULL` values.

It is also considered good coding style to explicitly list all columns in the `insert` statement: `insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3) ...`